# Is only one related list layout supported for each type of object in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

I have several record types setup for my Account object. For each Record Type I've created a unique page layout (App Setup->Customize->Accounts->Page Layouts) and associated to the correct Record Type with Page Layout Assignment.

I have a related child object (like Contacts) whose records can be seen on the page layout through its Related List. However each Record Type has different relevent fields for the records in the Related List. I've tried to change the column list on the Page Layout, but when I change the colums on one Page Layout it changes on *all* of the Page Layouts.

Is there a way for 2 Page Layouts to display the same kind of child object but with different columns? For example could I create two Account Page Layouts, but have different columns shown in the Related List of Contacts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you're leaving the "Apply column information to other page layouts:" check boxes checked, when you're doing your changes to the related list fields.

If you uncheck those, you'll be able to define related list columns separately for each of your layouts.

Comment: The most obvious answer is the best one. I don't know why, but that option was "hidden" for me by a scrollbar - everything else fit in the dialog window so I didn't realize there was another element. I'm running 1920x1080 so it's not like I'm hard up for screen space...